# Trigger query with ActiveJdbc in controller

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

I'm running a query using ActiveJdbc

```
List<Game> games = District.findAll("where createor_id = ?", creatorId);
```

And according o the documentation the query is triggered when I do this

```
    for (Game game : games) {
        //do things with result
    }
```

But I want to put the result in a ModelMap in order to use in in the jstl view (Spring mvc 4). So How can I trigger the query? right now in order to trigger the query I have to do

```
game.size();
```

But I guess it's an optimal solution.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the title of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about when the list will make a trip to the database. If you just pass the `games` object to the JSP, then it will make DB call during rendering of the page. Also, you do not need to make additional ModelMap, just pass a list to a view.

If  you insist on passing maps to JSP, you can do this:

```
List<Map> games = District.findAll("where createor_id = ?", creatorId).toMaps();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I don't use scriptlet I use jstl so I use my <c:foreach></c:foreach>. And it doesn't trigger anything if the List is empty. If I use it with scriptlet <% for (Game game : games) { } %> it would work. So yeah, I'll use the solution you gave me. Thanks.

Comment: in orde to know if the list is empty, someone will try to call `list.size()` or another method. This will trigger a trip to a database. In any case, glad it's working for you.